# How to reference a collection name with "." in Mongo db?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have a mongo DB, in the mongo shell, when I run "show collections", it returns the collection with dot in the collection name like

```
a.1
a.2
a.3
```

How I refer it in command like

```
db.a.1.find()
```

the above returns SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Comment: If you're going to answer your own question, you need to put more effort into explaining why the problem exists.  You should expand your answer into *why* it works that way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

figure it out. wrapping it in [ ]. basic javascript knowledge.

```
db["a.1"].find()
```

Comment: Same thing will work if your collection name has special characters like space , hypen ,..